# Using hitTest logic only for touchesBegan and NOT gesture recognizers

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have been developing a simple game for iOS which involves dragging and using rotation- and other gesture recognizers. Dragging is realized through `touchesBegan/Moved/Ended` and rotation - through recognizer.

The views are irregularly shaped, and the view borders sometimes overlap, so I implemented Ole Belgeman's [UIImage+ColorAtPixel](https://github.com/ole/OBShapedButton/tree/master/UIImage+ColorAtPixel) in my *picture view* and overrode `isPointInside` method in the main *element view*. isPointInside invokes the method in *picture view*, which checks alpha at touch point and returns NO if the transparent section has been touched. Essentially, `hitTest` ignores this branch.

But the side effect of it is that hitTest ignores all touches on the transparent section, and rotation recognizer only works on the non-transparent zone. For some views, which are too small in size, it becomes impossible to use rotation gesture :(

Is there any way to somehow avoid this problem and use `hitTest` logic **only** for `touchesBegan`? I tried to work the solution out, but it seems that hitTest works strictly before any touch handling.

Checking the transparency at `touchesBegan` works, but when you touch the transparent section, which overlaps the non-transparent section of the other view, the latter doesn't receive the touch.

I just can't figure out the trick...

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make the dragging use a [UIPanGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html), so that you can implement the delegate method [-gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate/gestureRecognizer%3ashouldReceiveTouch%3a) to return `NO` when your pan recognizer is considering touches in the transparent area. Leave it unimplemented or return `YES` from your rotation recognizer to receive everything.

In addition, using gesture recognizers for both kinds of actions has other benefits, like the ability to specify dependencies with [-requireGestureRecognizerToFail:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIGestureRecognizer/requireGestureRecognizerToFail%3a).

Answer (score 1):

Try to check if the UIEvent parameter that passed to pointInside:withEvent: when it comes from the gesture recognizer, is different than the one passed when it called from touchBegan/Moved/Ended.

If it is different then i guess this is solving your problem.

Just put a break point or NSLog at pointInside to see the Event parameter on each case and see if you can differentiate.

Good Luck!